# How to omit NA in the legend only

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

```r
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
```

Let's start with this simple plot:

```r
faithful %>%
    ggplot(aes(waiting, eruptions, color = eruptions > 3)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

Now, let's introduce some missing values in the class variable:

```r
faithful_with_missings <-
    faithful %>%
    mutate(eruptions_class = ifelse(eruptions > 3, '>3', '<=3'),
           eruptions_class = ifelse(rbinom(n(), 1, 0.9), eruptions_class, NA_character_))
           ##eruptions_class = as.factor(eruptions_class))
faithful_with_missings$eruptions_class %>% table(exclude = NULL)
#> .
#>  <=3   >3 <NA> 
#>   89  151   32
```

Redo the plot with missings:

```r
ggplot(faithful_with_missings, aes(waiting, eruptions, color = eruptions_class)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

Here is my question:
Is there a way to plot the NA points, but to omit NA in the legend?

My desired output is:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the categories to show up in the legend via the `breaks` argument of the scale. Hence, to drop the NAs you could use a lambda function in `scale_color_discrete` to drop the NAs:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(faithful_with_missings, aes(waiting, eruptions, color = eruptions_class)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_discrete(breaks = ~ .x[!is.na(.x)])
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks.  I was not even aware of the fact that I could use lambda functions in the breaks argument.

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `scale_color_manual` by knowing that the NA color is `grey50` and specify the `breaks` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(faithful_with_missings, aes(waiting, eruptions, color = eruptions_class)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "grey50"), breaks = c("<=3", ">3"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

If you want to use the standard colors of ggplot, you could use the `hue_pal` function from `scales` package to get the two colors like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(faithful_with_missings, aes(waiting, eruptions, color = eruptions_class)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(hue_pal()(2), "grey50"), breaks = c("<=3", ">3"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I very much like that. Using breaks on the colour scale had not occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach by tweaking `scale_color_manual` and `theme`:

```
library(ggplot2)

  ggplot(faithful_with_missings, aes(waiting, eruptions, color = eruptions_class)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "NA"),
                      limits = c("<=3",">3","")) +
    theme_bw()+
    theme(legend.background=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: That is a funny approach! Is only `theme_bw` also enough?

Comment: You are right! First I tried only with `theme(legend.background=element_blank())`. But it did not work.